# After reset, what will happen to persistent arrays declared and initialized in different ways?

Tags: java, applet, javacard

Assume the applet constructor and processToolkit method were called before card reset.
Assume only applet constructor is called after card reset, not processToolkit method.

I have the the following three questions regarding the state of Object header's after reset.

1. Will Object Header of array A be valid or just garbage?
2. Will Object Header of array B be valid or just garbage?
3. Will Object Header of array C be valid or just garbage?

For the following code:

```
public class TestApplet extends Applet 
{ 

    private byte[] A;
    private byte[] B;

    protected TestApplet() {
        A = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray(100, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
    }

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        TestApplet appToRegister = new TestApplet();
        appToRegister.register();
    }

    public void processToolkit(short event) throws ToolkitException {
        byte[] C;
        C = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray(100, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
        B = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray(100, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As per sensible and responsible JavaCard programming style, you shall not have C and shall make B next to A in the constructor and call the constructor only once during applet installation from `install()`. The rest is described in JavaCard runtime environment spec.

Answer (score 2):

The applet constructor can only be called once per instance. So if we are talking about a different instance then only A will have been declared *and* instantiated.

B will only have been declared, but note that fields are initialized by default in Java, specifically to `null` for object references (and references to *arrays* are treated as references to objects in Java).

C, of course, isn't known. It's local to `processToolkit` so it won't exist.

Note that the call to `Applet.register` seems to be missing in action, so the instance may not be available after it was instantiated.

---

The persistent memory claimed by the earlier instance (the object header) for C may need to be garbage collected of course. C is a known bad pattern in Java Card; you don't claim persistent memory only to throw away the reference afterwards in Java Card.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I added the install method for more clarity. So just to confirm, after reset, the object header of B will be initialized to `null`, and will not be pointing to the RAM address that it was pointing to before reset, correct?

Comment: Hmm, don't know why I didn't answer it at that time, but yeah, correct.